# I want to use assertion for the checkbox

Tags: cypress

I want to use assertion for this checkbox. It depends on duration. If it's checked duration = forever, if not = a month.

```
cy.wrap(cy.get('span.ant-checkbox').should('have.class','ant-checkbox-checked')).then((a) => {       
  if a == true {         
     cy.log('Forever')       
   }     
})
```

Comment: Do you just want to log `Forever` and `A month` based on if-else or you are looking for something else. Please update the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. You don't need to `cy.wrap()` your entire statement. `cy.wrap()` would primarily be used to wrap a JQuery yielded from `cy.get()` or a similar command, and insert it back into the Cypress command chain.
2. Your assertion that the element has a certain class will fail and stop your test before even getting to the `.then()` part of the command if the element does not have the `ant-checkbox-checked` class.

Instead, if we get the element, we can use JQuery functions (in this case, [`.hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/))to determine if it has the class we want.

```js
cy.get('span.ant-checkbox').then(($el) => {
  // cy.get yields a JQuery<HTMLElement>
  if ($el.hasClass('ant-checkbox-checked')) {
    cy.log('Forever');
  } else {
    cy.log('A month');
  }
});
```